# How to use reflections library to get subtype of a subtype

Tags: java, reflections

Here is my scenario, I have three classes:

```
public abstract class A {

    public Set<Class<?>> getGrandChildren() {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        Set<Class<?>> grandChildren = reflections.getSubTypesOf(this.getClass());
        return grandChildren;
    }

}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends B implements X {}

class D {

       public B client = new B();

       //I am trying to get all children of this class 
       client.getGrandChildren()    
}
```

My compiler complains about type of:

```
Set<Class<?>> grandChilderen = reflections.getSubTypesOf(this.getClass());
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to rely on the [`raw type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) as it fails because it expects a value for the parameterized type (corresping to `T` in the signature `public <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> getSubTypesOf(Class<T> type)`) which you cannot provide here as it is a generic method

```
public Set<Class<?>> getGrandChildren() {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
    Set grandChildren = reflections.getSubTypesOf(this.getClass());
    return grandChildren;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, I tried using <T> before but, casting (Class<T> type ) made the difference.